# My program works in vsc but not with when running it with pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, winapi, pyinstaller, pyautogui

I have an application with tkinter, win32gui and cv2. It is an app that compares images and when finding similarities it beeps through the Windows API. The problem is that when I run it from the EXE this sound and the detection doesn't work, but the program somehow does... how do I realize? Because if I bring the window forward, this lets me know that my app is working. But I don't know why the sound and the detection don't. Any suggestions?

Heres my windowscapture.py:

```
def SearchImage():
    hwnd_targets = []

    def enum_window_callback(hwnd, hwnd_targets):
        window_title = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
        if window_title == 'MU':
            hwnd_targets.append(hwnd)

    # Enumerar todas las ventanas y filtrar las que tengan el título "MU"
    win32gui.EnumWindows(enum_window_callback, hwnd_targets)

    for hwnd_target in hwnd_targets:
        print(hwnd_targets)

        left, top, right, bot = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd_target)
        w = right - left
        h = bot - top

        if (w != 1600 and h != 900):
            win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd_target, left, top, 1600, 900, True)
            #print("Redimensionando ventana: Altura", h, " Ancho", w)

        # Truco para que setForeground siempre funcione
        shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
        shell.SendKeys('%')
        win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd_target)

        hdesktop = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
        hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hdesktop)
        mfcDC  = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwndDC)
        saveDC = mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()

        saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
        saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, w, h)

        saveDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)

        result = saveDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (w, h), mfcDC, (left, top), win32con.SRCCOPY)

        bmpinfo = saveBitMap.GetInfo()
        bmpstr = saveBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)

        im = Image.frombuffer(
            'RGB',
            (bmpinfo['bmWidth'], bmpinfo['bmHeight']),
            bmpstr, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)

        win32gui.DeleteObject(saveBitMap.GetHandle())
        saveDC.DeleteDC()
        mfcDC.DeleteDC()
        win32gui.ReleaseDC(hdesktop, hwndDC)

        if result == None:
            return im, (left, top, right, bot)
            
        
        return None
```

Main.py:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import windowcapture
import pyautogui
import cv2
import winsound

def windowsbeep(duration, frequency):
    for _ in range(0,2):
        winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
        winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
        winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
        time.sleep(1)

def get_xy_center(coords, max_loc, template):
    left, top, _, _ = coords
    w, h = template.shape[::-1]
    return left + max_loc[0] + w/2, top + max_loc[1] + h/2

def Buscar_Imagen():
    pil_img, coords = windowcapture.SearchImage()
    img = cv2.cvtColor(np.asarray(pil_img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    return img, coords

def match_image(img, template):
    matching_method = cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED
    # Apply template Matching
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img, template, matching_method, mask=None)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
    return max_val, max_loc
    
def click(x, y):
    current_x, current_y = pyautogui.position()
    pyautogui.click(x, y)
    pyautogui.moveTo(current_x, current_y)

def searchTemplate(template, accuracy=0.87):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    img, coords = Buscar_Imagen()
    max_val, max_loc = match_image(img, template)

    if (max_val > accuracy):     
        # Get the coordinates of the center of the image 
        x, y = get_xy_center(coords, max_loc, template)
        # Click it
        click(x, y)
        return True, max_val
    else:
        return False, max_val
    
def main():
    Bless = cv2.imread('./templates/Bless.jpg', 0)
    Soul = cv2.imread('./templates/Soul.jpg', 0)
    Chaos = cv2.imread('./templates/Chaos.jpg', 0)
    Life = cv2.imread('./templates/Life.jpg', 0)
    Prueba = cv2.imread('./templates/Prueba.jpg', 0)

    while(True):
        try:
            # Bless
            found, max_val = searchTemplate(Bless, accuracy=0.9)
            print(found, max_val)
            if found:
                windowsbeep(100,500)
            # Soul
            found, max_val = searchTemplate(Soul, accuracy=0.9)
            print(found, max_val)
            if found:
                windowsbeep(100,500)
            # Chaos
            found, max_val = searchTemplate(Chaos, accuracy=0.9)
            print(found, max_val)
            if found:
                windowsbeep(100,500)
            found, max_val = searchTemplate(Life, accuracy=0.9)
            print(found, max_val)
            if found:
                windowsbeep(100,500)
            found, max_val = searchTemplate(Prueba)
            print(found, max_val)
            if found:
                windowsbeep(100,500)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e) 
        time.sleep(2)
```

tkinter.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from tkinter import messagebox, filedialog
import main


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#FUNCIONES DE LOS BOTONES

def infoCreador():
    messagebox.showinfo("Buscador de Objetos", "Creado por Julian Regueira")

def avisoSalir():
    opciones=messagebox.askquestion("Salir", "¿Deseas salir?")

    if opciones == "yes":
        root.destroy()

    else:
        pass

def abrirImagen():
    global show_img
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='Objetos/Joyas',
                                          title="Buscar Objeto",
                                          filetypes=(("Imagenes JPG", "*.JPG"), ("Imagenes PNG","*.PNG"), ("Todos los archivos", "*.*")))   
    show_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(filename))
    display_img = Label(image=show_img)
    display_img.config(width="150", height="50")
    display_img.pack()

def run():
    main.main()

def exit_program():
    root.destroy()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#CONFIGURACION GENERAL

#MAIN
root = tk.Tk()

#TITULO MAIN
root.title("Para Maxi")

#ICONO DE LA APP
root.iconbitmap("esq.ico")

#FONDO
root.config(bg="grey")

#TAMAÑO
root.geometry("250x150")
root.resizable(0,0)


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#BARRA DE ACCIONES
barraMenu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=barraMenu)

#Funcionalidad botones 1
Nuevo_Cargar=Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
Nuevo_Cargar.add_command(label="Nuevo item", command=abrirImagen)
Nuevo_Cargar.add_command(label="Cargar item")
Nuevo_Cargar.add_separator()
Nuevo_Cargar.add_command(label="Salir", command=avisoSalir)

#Funcionalidad botones 2
Ayuda=Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
Ayuda.add_command(label="Desarrollo")
Ayuda.add_command(label="Sobre el programa...", command=infoCreador)

#Distribucion MENU, add_cascade hace que aparezcan en la intrerfaz
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Archivo", menu=Nuevo_Cargar)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Ayuda", menu=Ayuda)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#BOTON START

boton_start = tk.Button(root, text= "Start", width="20", height="2", command=run)
boton_start.place(x=50, y=25)

boton_salir = tk.Button(root, text="Exit", width="10", height="2", command=exit_program)
boton_salir.place(x=85, y=75)

#FUNCIONALIDAD DEL BOTON PARA COMENZAR

root.mainloop()
```